# are both stderror and stdout printed on the screen?

Tags: bash

Where can I find the STDERR if I run I bash command. Will both the STDOUT and STDERR be displayed on the screen simultaneously if I don't log the result in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "find" `stdout` or `stderr`. By default they're redirected to the screen.

You can redirect them to a file for example:

- redirect `stdout` to a `ls-l.txt`:

  ```
  ls -l > ls-l.txt
  ```
- redirect `stderr` to `grep-errors.txt`

  ```
  grep da * 2> grep-errors.txt
  ```
- redirect `stdout` to `stderr`:

  ```
  grep da * 1>&2
  ```

All of this is well explained here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Answer (score 2):

They will be both connected to your terminal unless you specify a redirection.

Try something like

```
ls -l /proc/self/fd
```

and you'll see the associated file descriptors for your shell

```
total 0
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Feb 11 14:16 0 -> /dev/pts/8
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Feb 11 14:16 1 -> /dev/pts/8
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Feb 11 14:16 2 -> /dev/pts/8
```

Comment: What does 0 -> /dev/pts/8 refer to?

Comment: In UNIX, a file descriptor is simply an integer associated with an open file. In the above, it means that file descriptor 0 (also known as standard input) is associated with the file /dev/pts/8, which is the representation of a terminal in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to test:

```
$ echo 'stdout'
stdout
$ echo 'stderr' >/dev/stderr
stderr
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessarily.  In theory at least, stdout (file descriptor 1) and stderr (file descriptor 2) are different.  stdout is *buffered*, stderr is not.  The idea is that a buffer is more efficient for stdout, but errors should not be delayed by a buffer.  It is possible to get these two out of sync, however it is unlikely.

In practice, terminal systems use line buffering, appending the "\n" (newline) will flush the stdout buffer so the problem rarely occurs (although "rarely" is not the same as "never").

From C it is possible to *write* to file descriptor (fd) 0 (stdin) and *read* from fds 1 and 2, since the terminal driver only knows input/output (confuses the hell out of people).